# Can I extract my apk file to retrieve lost files?

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, onedrive

I've been working on a mobile game in Unity for over a month, saving all my work to OneDrive. Today I restarted my computer and when it loaded back up I tried opening my project and it failed. I looked through my OneDrive and half my files are missing! I've been on the phone with Microsoft support all day and I can't get those files back.

I have the apk file for the game loaded onto my phone. Is there anyway to reverse build this thing back onto Unity or just get the files back from the apk file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by APK you mean Android's APK file you can just 'unzip' it and get at least you xml files and other resources such as images. All classes will be packed to classes.dex file, which can be converted to Java's JAR by dex2jar tool. However JAR will give you only Java's binaries. You could further de-compile them to Java files, but they are not going to look pretty or very readable.

Well, at least you can recover you XML layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Are the files in your recycle bin on the OneDrive website or locally?  Often times when OneDrive files go missing they can be found there.

Comment: I had been saving to OneDrive locally. I searched the recycle bin and they are not in there.                                                                     I changed a bunch of script names in my project and those are the files that have disappeared as well as an entire scene file that I had been working on

Comment: Have you looked at the recycle bin on the OneDrive website?  Even when only interacting with files locally they can wind up there if deleted.

Comment: Yeah I checked both locally and online. Spent a lot of time on the phone with Microsoft support to try and fix the issue but it seems the files are lost forever.